# How to let Windows 7 laptop provide an internet connection to my Android?

Tags: windows-7, android, tethering

Google didn't help me at all on this. I have a Samsung Galaxy S mobile phone, running Android 2.3.3. I'm wondering whether it's possible to have my laptop providing an internet connection for it. I guess a sort of tethering, but reversed.

Prerequisites for that is the mobile phone, to connect to the Internet not directly but through a Windows machine. Can you help me? Ad hoc networking (as proposed in another thread) doesn't seem to work in my situation.

Thank you :)

Comment: Does your current mobile phone contract allow you to tether the phone and share the internet connection, or is this something you would have to pay extra for?  Because unless you have rooted the phone, you would have to pay extra to be able to use the phone as a wireless hot spot... with most plans.

Comment: My phone is rooted and we dont have such restrictions in my country :)

Comment: Excellent!  I didn't know that those kinds of restrictions were mandated by countries and governments.  Here in the US, those kinds of  restrictions are handled by the companies that sell the cell phone contracts, and the restrictions vary from company to company.  I just wanted to make the comment asking those questions, since you didn't cover those things in *your* question, and if you had not thought of those things, they could have caused your issues.  You know... necessary information and such.

Comment: But... just to ask... if your country does not restrict phone usage like that... why did you have to root it?

Comment: Basically to remove unwanted applications...and to to tether. :)

Comment: so... your country does not place restrictions on phone usage such as tethering, but you had to root it to tether it.  Odd... but Ok.

Comment: The software I found for that purpose required root privileges...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just installed [Virtual Router - Wifi Hot Spot for Windows](https://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/) on my Windows 7 laptop. I can now connect my Asus Nexus Android device to the internet through my laptop.

That tool creates... guess what :) a virtual wireless router!

It lets you enter a name for the SSID (network name), a password and choose which connection you'd like to share. That's it. It also shows you which devices are connected to it.

Answer (score 3):

> To connect to the Internet not directly but through a Windows machine.
>   Can you help me?

I have added my answer little more related to your question. I assume that the first method will clear your question.

**1.Sharing your PC's internet to mobile via USB :**

While connecting your mobile to your windows machine you need to choose the option **Internet pass-through**  in your Android mobile as shown below.
***Note:-***
* For that you need to install samsung mobile driver software called [KIES](http://www.samsung.com/in/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP) .If you don't have that software already then download directly from [here](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/SW/201105/20110512115717796/Kies_2.3.2.12054_20_1.exe).
* Allow access if your Internet security software blocks or edit the security options in firewall.

[image]

**2.Sharing your mobile internet via PC :**

After tethering , go to **Network sharing center** and click **Change adapter settings**.

In my case i am using HTC mobile and tethered shown below for example..

[image]
Now right click the active samsung remote network icon and click **properties**,
In **Sharing** tab Tick the **check box** ,Now your laptop will share your internet connection to your ad-hoc computer connected via LAn or WiFi ...

[image]

You can also choose the connection type like this depends on your network adapter..

[image]

Comment: Cool...let me check and I will come back...

Comment: What do you mean by  "active samsung remote network"?? Can you guide me from the beggining please?

Comment: @peraueb1989 can you find the network icon for your connection ?

Comment: No, neither the dropdown menu as on your screenshots

Comment: You connected your mobile via tethering with laptop is working right?

Comment: @peraueb1989 Now i have a question and doubt, Do you want to share your mobile internet to PC via tethering? or Going to use Internet connection via your PC to your Mobile?

Comment: The second one...sorry if I wasnt clear :)

Answer (score -2):

Try [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/). It creates a hotspot(like any other Android phone does) and allows other devices to access your laptop's internet connection.

Comment: What does this software do that previous accepted answer does not have?  This is also paid software and the trial software is extremely limited.