# How to use Internet from Windows PC to Android tablet?

Tags: windows-7, networking, android

I am using Windows 7 PC and Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 p3100 tablet.
I use internet mostly on my PC. But i also want to use on my tablet, but i don't know how..

"I don't want to use any router or something."

So, without any router is there any way to use internet from my PC to tablet? I just know how to use internet on PC from Tablet. (ie, by USB Tethering)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can share your laptop's connection over Wi-Fi, you're essentially turning your laptop into a Wi-Fi hotspot and connect Your tablet than.

You have few options:
1
Use Internet Connection Sharing (ICS): Internet Connection Sharing or ICS is built into Windows computers from Windows 98 to above. An example of Internet Connection Sharing is if you have a laptop connected via wire to a router or modem and then share that connection to a phone or tablet either over the Wi-Fi adapter or through another Ethernet port. 
Here is instructions for Windows 7:
http://mobileoffice.about.com/od/internet-sharing-tethering/ht/how-to-share-internet-connection-on-windows7.htm

2
You can use Connectify:

Connectify is free software that shares a single Wi-Fi connection over Wi-Fi--no need for a second adapter or for your laptop to be wired to the Internet. It's only available for Windows 7 and above, however. One of the main advantages of Connectify over the above methods is that the connection is more secure--using WPA2 encryption in Access Point Mode versus the very insecure WEP, as the ad hoc networking modes above do. See these instructions for turning your Windowsx laptop into a Wi-Fi hotspot for your phone and other devices:
http://mobileoffice.about.com/od/internet-sharing-tethering/ht/how-to-share-your-windows7-wifi-connection.htm

There is more information:
1
[How to let Windows 7 laptop provide an internet connection to my Android?](https://superuser.com/questions/434628/how-to-let-windows-7-laptop-provide-an-internet-connection-to-my-android)  
2 
http://smartphones.wonderhowto.com/how-to/tether-laptop-droid-smartphone-for-free-wifi-354620/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check out Reverse USB Tethering. You will need root, though. There may be some cases where root isn't needed, but I'm not sure about them.

[Play Store App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jasongong.tether.usb&hl=en)

[XDA Forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2287494)

[XDA Developers](https://www.xda-developers.com/android/usb-reverse-tethering-guide-no-software-required/)